# MIPS counting digits in unsigned integer

Tags: assembly, mips

A user enters a binary number(ie: 110100), I need to calculate the number of consecutive 0's starting from the LSB, so it would be 2 in the case of 110100.

My problem is counting the length of this entered string. But I found this to be impossible because im checking by way of

```
      beqz $t2,finished
```

which will immeadiately stop at the first 0 at 110, even though we know this is not the end of the string.

My attempt:

```
    ## Read string from user ##
    la $a0, str
    li $a1, 100
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
    ##

    ## Loop each byte in string until null-terminator is found ##
    loop:
        move $t0,$t1
        add $t0,$t0,$a0 # current address($t0)=counter*1(size of character in bytes)+RAM address of start of array

        lb $t2,($t0)    # load next byte in string 

        lw $s0, del

        beqz $t2,finished   # if current character==null-terminator, exit loop

        addi $t1,$t1,1  # increase counter

        beqz $t2,addtoh

        j loop  # loop around

    addtoh:
        addi $t3,$t3,1 #
        j loop  # loop around
    finished:
    ##

#################################################
#                                               #
#               data segment                    #
#                                               #
#################################################

            .data
        str:    .space 100
        endl:   .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: The text character `'0'` is (in ASCII/UTF-8/whatever-character-set-you-are-likely-using) coded as 48 (decimal), not 0.  If someone enters the character-sequence `'1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'` (as six adjacent bytes) these are 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, and 48 respectively.  However, the `read` system call (I assume syscall #8, in `v0`, is `read`) probably returns the number of bytes read, rather than creating a zero-byte-terminated string, in the first place.

Comment: They aren't read in ASCII(48 and 49s) though, they are read as 0 and 1s, how do I fix this?

Comment: What are you `read`-ing from, a user-interaction device, a file on a file system?  What OS is handling the `syscall` instruction?  What return value(s) does syscall #8 return, in which registers?

Comment: Windows. I am reading in a string(syscall 8), storeing that address in $a0, then reading each character in the string with load byte(1 byte per character) lb $t2,($t0)

Comment: Aha, this appears be be based on [SPIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM) ([UWisc](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html)).  In that case, yes, the `read_string` system call should read a string a la C's `fgets`, terminated with a zero byte.  ASCII input should be ASCII-encoded.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, and im using pcspim.

Comment: According to the SPIM documentation, the simulated system call should fill the buffer with ASCII text.  That is, if you type `110100` in, the buffer should contain bytes 49, 49, 48, etc.  That's about all I can tell from the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fill it with ASCII values, or at least the way I fill the buffer. I use syscall 8, read string, into the buffer, then lb(load byte) with the address of each character in string, and that lb DOES NOT return ASCII values :(

Comment: It seems a bit bizarre that sycall 8 would not be generating a string with ASCII values. What does it generate when you enter "foo0123bar"?

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem - added answer.

Comment: Solved, the argument register $a0 was corrupting my data, so I moved $a0 to a temporary register before looping the string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're initializing `$t1`. Unlike high-level languages, machine code doesn't initialize memory or registers automatically. `$t1` could be starting out anywhere. So when you do this:

```
move $t0,$t1    # unknown 32-bit value loaded into $t0
add $t0,$t0,$a0 # $t0 is now an unknown number of bytes past (or before!) the start of the buffer
lb $t2,($t0)    # load next (random) byte in string
```

... you could end up looking at bytes anywhere in the memory space. And since a lot of those bytes *will* end up being zero, your code will finish sooner than you expected.

Comment: So, what *does* it generate when instead of a string like "110100", you enter "foo110100bar"? If a "1" is 1 and "0" is 0, what's an "f" or an "o"?

Comment: Solved, the argument register $a0 was corrupting my data, so I moved $a0 to a temporary register before looping the string.